# memory access profiling of C/C++ programs

Tags: c++, c, performance, memory, memory-management

I am exploring memory access profiling of C/C++ programs.
I would like to know when memory access started, how long it takes to perform memory access, and the type of memory accessed (L1/L2/L3/DRAM).

I used a tool named *lmbench* which performs memory access latency profiling. The "lat_mem_rd" benchmark in lmbench measures the latency of sequential memory reads. This benchmark performs a series of sequential memory reads on a specified memory block and reports the average latency for each read. The latency is measured in nanoseconds, and lower values indicate better memory access performance. Using this tool I can get the latency in accessing L1, L2, L3, DRAM memory.

I understand that *CPU architecture* and *compiler optimizations* plays a key role in program optimization, which may affect the overall memory access latency. OS context switching also increases the memory access latency.

Are there any profiling tools available or known proven techniques to get the near-to-exact memory access profiling information? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Intel VTune Amplifier: This is a performance profiling tool that can analyze the memory access behavior of C/C++ programs on Intel processors.
- AMD CodeXL: This is a performance analysis tool that can profile C/C++ programs running on AMD processors.
- HPCToolkit: This is an open-source performance analysis tool that can profile C/C++ programs on various architectures, including x86, ARM, and PowerPC.

you can also use hardware performance counters available on most modern CPUs to get insights into memory access performance. These performance counters can track memory access events such as cache hits/misses, memory bandwidth usage, and more.